# Pygame pixel perfect collision not working as expected

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, tetris, pixel-perfect

I am creating tetris using pygame. i want to use collision detection so that when the shape in play comes into contact with any other previously played shapes, i can stop the shape, as per the logic of tetris. i came across pixel perfect collision using masks. i have followed some tutorials online, however the pixel detection returns true every time a new shape comes into play, not when any shapes collide.  sorry in advance for the long code, its the bare minimum for the code to actually and still containing the game element of it. i think there is something wrong with my approach which is causing this error. I basically have a function that everytime the shape in play comes into contact with the 'floor' that shape is held in that position and a new shape is created. i think ive overcomplicated it, in turn creating this error. thanks in advance

```
import pygame
import sys
import shapelogic

pygame.init()

screensize = width, height = 800, 595

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)



background_image =pygame.image.load("/Users/marceason/PycharmProjects/Tetris/Wooden_background.jpg").convert_alpha()

myshape = 0
stop_movement = 0
blit_count = 0
stored_shapes = pygame.sprite.Group()
stored_shapes_with_coords = []
extra_blit_required = False


index = 0
count = 0
listofshapes = []

class shapemanager():

    def __init__(self):

        self.listofshapes = []


    def create_another_instance(self):

        global count
        count += 1
        string = "Shape_{0},".format(count)

        another_shape = Shape(string)
        self.listofshapes.append(another_shape)
        global index
        object = self.listofshapes[index]
        index += 1
        return object


def load_shape(self):
    shape = self.create_another_instance()
    shape.load_shapes()







class Shape(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, name):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.name = name
    self.x = 50
    self.y = 100
    self.move_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    self.reached_bottom_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
    self.one_sec_timer = 1000
    self.half_sec_timer = 500

    self.reachbottomflag = False
    self.movement_possible = True

    self.image = pygame.image.load(
"/Users/marceason/PycharmProjects/Tetris/Tetris_Shapes/Green_Shape_1_Position_1.png")
    self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


def move_shape(self):
    if self.movement_possible:
        key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key_input[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 16
        if key_input[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 16
        if not self.reachbottomflag:
            if key_input[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.y += 16


def reachbottom(self):

    if self.y >= 560:
        self.reachbottomflag = True

def no_movement_possible(self):

    self.movement_possible = False





def assign_shape():

global myshape
global stop_movement
myshape = sl.create_another_instance()
pygame.time.set_timer(myshape.move_event, myshape.one_sec_timer)
stop_movement = pygame.time.set_timer(myshape.reached_bottom_event, myshape.half_sec_timer)


def blit_used_shapes():

global screen
global blit_count
blit_count = len(stored_shapes_with_coords)
local_count = 0
while local_count < blit_count:
    screen.blit(stored_shapes_with_coords[local_count][0], (stored_shapes_with_coords[local_count][1], stored_shapes_with_coords[local_count][2]))
    local_count += 1


sl = shapemanager()





##### HERE IS THE PIXEL DETECTION #####
result = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(myshape, stored_shapes, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)


## Main loop ##

assign_shape()

while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(myshape.image, (myshape.x, myshape.y))
    myshape.move_shape()



    key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_input[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        myshape.rotate_shape()


    myshape.reachbottom()
    if myshape.reachbottomflag:
        if event.type == myshape.reached_bottom_event:
            myshape.no_movement_possible()
            stored_shape_tuple = [myshape.image, myshape.x, myshape.y]
            stored_shapes_with_coords.append(stored_shape_tuple)
            stored_shapes.add(myshape)

            extra_blit_required = True

            assign_shape()
            ####### PIXEL DETECTION IS HERE IN FOR LOOP ####
            if result:
                print("this should only execute when two shapes touch!!")

    if extra_blit_required:
        blit_used_shapes()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: why to use perfect collision for squares ? It is only waste of time.

Comment: you should use `print()` to check values in variables - it is called `print debuging`. OR learn how to use real debuger. Maybe it checks collision with different elements then you expect and this gives always `True`.  Sometimes people use `.x`, `.y` to move object but they forgot that pygame uses `.rect` to check collision and they forgot to change `.rect.x`, `.rect.y`. You should use only `.rect.x` and `.rect.y` to move and draw it `blit(shape.image, shape.rect)`

Comment: BTW: instead of checking `self.x >= 560` you could check `self.rect.bottom >= 595` (widow's height)

Comment: BTW: if you use classes then instead of global `index`, `count` you could  use `self.index` and `self.count`

Comment: your code has wrong indentations so it is useless - we can't run it. Always put code with correct indentations and use button `{}` or shortcut `Ctrl+K` to format it in question.

Comment: BTW: to make code more readagle put all classes and function before `pygame.init()` - see more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks for the comments furas. I will take note for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are not updating the sprites `rect` attribute. The sprites `rect`s all have position (0, 0) (since you do not set it in the call to `self.image.get_rect()`) and as a result the masks will all overlap and collide.

If you read the docs for [pygame.sprite.collide_mask](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) you will note that it says that your sprites need to have `mask` and `rect` attributes. You have a `rect` in your sprite and you set it in the `__init__()`, but you do not keep it updated when you move the sprite. You just change the `x` and `y` attributes without adjusting the `rect` position. The reason that the `collide_mask` wants a `rect` is that it uses that to determine the `offset` parameter for the [pygame.mask.Mask.overlap()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) call that it uses. The important thing to realize is that masks themselves do not have a position, they need the `rect`s to determine the relative positions of the masks.

This is similar to images/surfaces not having a position and needing a `rect` to track that for them.

On a separate issue, the way you are blit'ing the sprites to the screen makes no sense. You are not using the abilities of the sprite groups to draw and worse you are keeping the image, x and y of the sprite in a separate list and not containing it in the sprite itself. You should go look at some examples of pygame sprite based code. There are lots of examples out there.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, you have helped me understand masks a little bit more.i have amended the code as to update rects and have changed the way images are blitted to the screen (using a for loop through the sprite group ). the funny thing is now the collision NEVER activates.....

Comment: @Pyson The rect is also used to simplify the collision. Doing a mask-based collision is a relatively expensive operation, so the rects are first checked to see if they collide.  If the rect's do not collide, then there is not even a  need to check the masks.